# Delete All Cookie in Sub-domain that is Set for Main domain

Tags: apache, cookies, http-headers

Can I use the following to delete all cookies which are set from main domain:

1)

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
RequestHeader unset Cookie
</IfModule>
```

2)

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset Set-Cookie
</IfModule>
```

I want to satisfy this rule:

**Google page speed: Server static content from cookie less domain.**

Which of the above will be better and why?

**Update:**
I want to delete cookie in subdomain that is meant for main domain but it comes. I see it comes through adsense, cpanel, and others. CloudFlare is also adding cookie that is for main domain but it coming on subdomain.

Comment: It seems a patch for something wrong elsewhere. Why do you _set_ cookies if you don't _want_ cookies? If you must, unsetting the cookies from a request does nothing for you, only prevent them setting them yourself, _but_ you destroy your possibility of actually _unsetting_ that cookie on the client (as that is done with a `Set-Cookie` header...)

Comment: Updated the question with "Update". I think in my case it wont work. As when user visit example.com then again new cookie will be set and subdomain which is used for img will have all those cookies. 
But what if no new cookies are set from main domain? Then the solution will work.  Just to make question/answer useful for others.

Comment: Solution: if your 'cookieless' domain is something like `static.domain.com`, make any `non-static.domain.com` (this includes `www.` & no subdomain) only set cookies for that _specific_ subdomain, not `.domain.com`. Or, just register another domain you'll be using exclusively as static/cdn domain. A couple of bucks yearly or some hours work now, I'm sure you can do the math.

Comment: Ya, it looks separate domain is the best solution. 
I am using cloudfront for static but used subdomain to map it. Using external domain (cloudfront domain) in resource like images ask too much to change everything in all those blog post. But for my own blog I can live with few cookie. Wordpress has implemented a way to set cookie only for domain and I have that in place.